# Exception thrown while rendering rdlc file

Tags: c#, exception, dataset, datasource, rdlc

Following code throws exception while debugging-

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Customise parameters for render method
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamIds;
            string mimeType = "application/pdf";
            string encoding = String.Empty;
            string filenameExtension = String.Empty;
            string deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo>" + "<OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" + "<PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" + "<PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" + "<MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" + "<MarginLeft>1in</MarginLeft>" + "<MarginRight>1in</MarginRight>" + "<MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" + "</DeviceInfo>";

            //Create a SqlConnection to the AdventureWorks2008R2 database. 
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("data source=localhost;initial catalog=AdventureWorks2008R2;integrated security=True");

            //Create a SqlDataAdapter for the Sales.Customer table.
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

            // A table mapping names the DataTable.
            adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Sales.Customer");

            // Open the connection.
            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe SqlConnection is open.");

            // Create a SqlCommand to retrieve Suppliers data.
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Sales.Customer.CustomerID,Sales.Customer.PersonID,Sales.Customer.StoreID,Sales.Customer.TerritoryID,Sales.Customer.AccountNumber,Sales.Customer.rowguid,Sales.Customer.ModifiedDate FROM Sales.Customer", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            // Set the SqlDataAdapter's SelectCommand.
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Fill the DataSet.
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet("Sales.Customer");

            adapter.Fill(dataset);

            //set up Reportviewver
            Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport viewer = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport();
            viewer.ReportPath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\murali.madhava\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\PdfReportGeneration\PdfReportGeneration\Report.rdlc";


           //add data source.
           viewer.DataSources.Clear();
           viewer.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dataset", dataset.Tables[0]));


           //Now render it to pdf
           try
           {
            byte[] bytes = viewer.Render("PDF", deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamIds, out warnings);
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("output.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Create))
            {
                //file saved to bin directory
                    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }

                //Save report to D:\
                // FileStream fsi = new FileStream(@"D:\output.pdf", FileMode.Create);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nCHEY!!!this Exception encountered:", e);
            }


                        // Close the connection.
                        connection.Close();
                        Console.WriteLine("\nThe SqlConnection is closed.");
                        Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
```

The Winform version used is 9.0.0.0 and i used Adventureworks2008R2.Exception says :"An error occurred during local report processing". How to encounter this?

Comment: Have you been able to run the report in the report designer?  Also, does the exception have an inner exception?  If so, what does it say?

Comment: Inner exception says: An error has occurred during report processing.I have created the report in VS2008 ; a Report.rdlc file - its a part of the same console application.Without data if i try to run with "Hello World" pdf generated

Comment: Does the inner exception itself have an inner exception?  If so, what does it say?  (At some point, it should actually say what the error was.)  Also, when you created the report file in VS 2008, did you drag fields to the report from a project Data Source?  What is that data source called?  For example, I just created one that's called `AnnsDBDataSet_Customers` and is the `Customers` table from a dataset created from `AnnsDB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the problem lies in the statement

```
viewer.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dataset", dataset.Tables[0]));
```

here the "dataset" name mentioned should be same as the dataset name usedin .rdlc report.Click on the report element proprty to see which dataset it uses.And Provide the exactly same data from query dataset 'dataset.Tables[0]'. It works.